# Cancel alarm with different context

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-context

I've a alarm created in an OnBootReceiver like this:

```
public class OnBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);

            Intent i = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), savedIntervalAutomaticMilisInt, pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

But to cancel it, I use this code in an Activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
scManager.clearErrors();
```

So to set it up I use the context from the BroadcastReceiver's Context parameter, but to cancel it I use the `this` context from the Activity. My question: Will the alarm still be cancelled, even though the context is slightly different?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Will the alarm still be cancelled, even though the context is slightly different?

Context does not matter in this case -- it is merely a way to get to an `AlarmManager`.

Your choice of `PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT` in your cancel-the-alarm logic may cause a problem. If you run into difficulties (e.g., `adb shell dumpsys alarm` indicates your alarm survived the cancel), try replacing `PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT` with `0`.

Comment: Okay, thanx, but why could it cause a problem?

Comment: @Merlin: `FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT` says "nuke the previous `PendingIntent` instance from orbit". Whatever data structure Android uses for holding alarms might be keyed by `PendingIntent` and might rely on `PendingIntent` instances being the same, based on normal `PendingIntent` construction. IOW, don't throw flags around willy-nilly -- only use `FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT` when you know precisely why you need it in a particular situation.

Comment: I use the flag because when I recreate the alarm in the OnBootReceiver, and for some reason the alarm hasn't been cancelled when the phone bootted off, I avoid having the alarm set twice.

Comment: @Merlin: I was referring to your use of `FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT` in your cancel-the-alarm logic, not in `OnBootReceiver`.

Comment: But if I remove the FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT in de cancel-the-alarm logic, then the two pendingIntents don't match anymore right?

Comment: @Merlin: Not only do they match, they will be the exact same `PendingIntent` object.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment about `FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT`. I really didn't understand why my cancel() didn't work, but removing that flag solved the problem I've been struggling with for months. I really don't understand why this isn't made clear in de doc. Thank you so much for your help! It's highly appreciated!

Comment: @CommonsWare You're amazing, as usual - I didn't understand why cancel didn't nuke the alarm lines from dumpsys (even though the actual alarms seem to be canceled correctly) - thanks

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try for a global (application-wide) context object: android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext()

Comment: Maybe it's not such a bad idea to use that one. Thanks! However, it doesn't really answer the question